# In JavaScript, how to stop execution of a Promise which lost a Promise.race?

Tags: javascript, timeout, es6-promise, cancellation, abortcontroller

I did not find a straightforward way to stop execution of a Promise when using `AbortController`. Let me explain.

To await async function **_aget_Cards** within a time limit defined by *timeout* parameter, I created two Promises and raced them as per the code block below.

```
async function xxx (userCN :string, timeout :number) :Promise<CardDetailsWithCCBal[]|unknown> {
    const controller = new AbortController()
    const raced_promise =  Promise.race ([
        new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
            _aget_Cards (resolve, reject, userCN, controller)
        }),
        new Promise ( (resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout ( () => reject('CONTROLLER_TIMEOUT'), timeout)
        })
    ])
    raced_promise.catch((error) => {
        console.log ('Error on raced promise detected')
        if (error === 'CONTROLLER_TIMEOUT') {
            console.log ('Detected error is a CONTROLLER_TIMEOUT ... Sending "abort" signal to controller for _aget_Cards')
            controller.abort()
        }
    })
    return raced_promise
}
```

You will note that I raised a specific 'CONTROLLER_TIMEOUT' error with `reject('CONTROLLER_TIMEOUT')` if the time limit Promise completes earlier. In the handling of that specific error, I invoke an abort() on the AbortController with `controller.abort()`.

The callbacks `resolve`, `reject` and the AbortController instance `controller` are passed as parameters in the first Promise `_aget_Cards (resolve, reject, userCN, controller)`.

In the `controller.signal.addEventListener` of the **_aget_Cards** function, I set `doAbort = true`, as per code block below.

```
async function _aget_Cards (resolve :(value :unknown) => void, reject :(reason ?:any) => void, userCN :string, controller :AbortController)  { 
    
    let doAbort = false
    controller.signal.addEventListener ("abort", () => {
        console.log ('Controller received "abort" signal ... aborting ...')
        doAbort = true
    })  

    let start_time = Date.now()
    if (doAbort) return
    const cardDetails_lists :CardDetails[][] = await Promise.all ( [
        aget_CardDetails_List (userCN, true),  // Get Primary cards
        aget_CardDetails_List (userCN, false)  // Get Secondary cards
    ])
    console.log(`List of Primary and Secondary Cards obtained in ${(Date.now()-start_time)/1000}s`)
    
    start_time = Date.now()
    if (doAbort) return
    const cardDetails_list :CardDetails[] = [...cardDetails_lists[0], ...cardDetails_lists[1]]
    cardDetails_list.sort ( (a, b) => {
        let a_sortVal :string = `${a.cardType}${a.cardNo}`
        let b_sortVal :string = `${b.cardType}${b.cardNo}`
        return (a_sortVal < b_sortVal) ? -1 : (a_sortVal > b_sortVal) ? 1 : 0 
    })

    if (doAbort) return
...
```

You will note that I have been using `if (doAbort) return` in more than one place to abort execution. I did not find a straightforward way to force the return when an abort was detected.

Rejecting the promise with `reject` inside `controller.signal.addEventListener` does not affect the execution of **_aget_Cards**. Neither does raising an error.

Your help would be much appreciated.

Comment: *"stop execution of a Promise"*: a promise doesn't execute. It is an object.

Comment: What does `aget_CardDetails_List` do? Please show us its code as well

Answer (score 0):

> I have been using `if (doAbort) return` in more than one place to abort execution. I did not find a straightforward way to force the return when an abort was detected.

Yes, it's not as straighforward as registering the abort signal with `async function` execution to abort execution (typically during `await`) when the signal is raised. JavaScript has no such feature :-/

Testing manually means that you stay in control of the places where control flow may be aborted. In your case, you are e.g. testing before and after the sorting, so that the sorting itself cannot be "interrupted" - it executes either all or nothing.

However, you can simplify your code quite a bit:

- do not use `Promise.race` with a promise that rejects after a certain time. Just abort the `controller` after a certain time
- instead of constructing the `AbortController` manually and doing `setTimeout` and `controller.abort()` yourself, use the [`AbortSignal.timeout()` helper function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortSignal/timeout_static)
- avoid [passing an `async function` as the executor to `new Promise`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43036229/1048572)! You already get the promise by just calling the function, and you won't have to deal with calling `resolve()`/`reject()` at the right time
- pass only the `AbortSignal` to the function that should *be stopped*, not the whole `AbortController`. You pass the controller to functions that should be able to *stop others*.
- do not use a boolean variable `doAbort` that you set yourself in an event listener on the abort signal. Just refer to [`signal.aborted`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortSignal/aborted)
- do not use `if (signal.aborted) return`, rather call [`signal.throwIfAborted()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortSignal/throwIfAborted) that will throw the abort reason and have it propagate up the call stack as an exception

So your code becomes

```
async function xxx(userCN: string, timeout: number): Promise<CardDetailsWithCCBal[]|unknown> {
    const signal = AbortSignal.timeout(timeout)
    return _aget_Cards(userCN, signal).catch(error => {
        console.log ('Error on promise detected')
        if (error === signal.reason) {
            console.log ('Detected error is a CONTROLLER_TIMEOUT...')
        }
        throw e
    })
}

async function _aget_Cards (userCN: string, signal: AbortSignal) {
    let start_time = Date.now()
    signal.throwIfAborted()
    const cardDetails_lists: CardDetails[][] = await Promise.all([
        aget_CardDetails_List(userCN, true),  // Get Primary cards
        aget_CardDetails_List(userCN, false)  // Get Secondary cards
    ])
    console.log(`List of Primary and Secondary Cards obtained in ${(Date.now()-start_time)/1000}s`)
    
    start_time = Date.now()
    signal.throwIfAborted()
    const cardDetails_list: cardDetails_lists.flat().sort((a, b) => {
        let a_sortVal: string = `${a.cardType}${a.cardNo}`
        let b_sortVal: string = `${b.cardType}${b.cardNo}`
        return (a_sortVal < b_sortVal) ? -1 : (a_sortVal > b_sortVal) ? 1 : 0 
    })
    signal.throwIfAborted()
    …
}
```

Finally, you don't need to call `signal.throwIfAborted()` that often. The signal would not fire while your synchronous code executes, so if it was not already aborted before the sorting it won't be aborted immediately after the sorting either. You normally only need this method to check *after an `await`* whether the signal has been triggered in the meantime. Even better though would be make the promise that you're `await`ing reject early when the signal fires, by passing the signal to the function you're calling and handling it inside there:

```
async function _aget_Cards (userCN: string, signal: AbortSignal) {
    let start_time = Date.now()
    const cardDetails_lists: CardDetails[][] = await Promise.all([
        aget_CardDetails_List(userCN, true, signal),  // Get Primary cards
//                                          ^^^^^^
        aget_CardDetails_List(userCN, false, signal)  // Get Secondary cards
//                                           ^^^^^^
    ])
    console.log(`List of Primary and Secondary Cards obtained in ${(Date.now()-start_time)/1000}s`)
    
    start_time = Date.now()
    const cardDetails_list: cardDetails_lists.flat().sort((a, b) => {
        let a_sortVal: string = `${a.cardType}${a.cardNo}`
        let b_sortVal: string = `${b.cardType}${b.cardNo}`
        return (a_sortVal < b_sortVal) ? -1 : (a_sortVal > b_sortVal) ? 1 : 0 
    })
    …
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Thank you [Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi) for bringing to my attention the *anti-pattern for Promise constructor*, and for your other comments to simplify the code, like eliminating the *Promise.race* to handle the timeout.

I reviewed my code and simplified it so that I would not even have to use **AbortController**.

The entry-point async function **aget_Cards** is called by the client as per code below.

```
// Call made by Client
let start_time = Date.now()
aget_Cards('9999',8000)
    .then ( (cardDetailsWithCCBal_list :CardDetailsWithCCBal[]|unknown) => {
        console.log (cardDetailsWithCCBal_list)
        console.log(`\n\nAll finished in ${(Date.now()-start_time)/1000}s`)
    })
    .catch ( (error :Error) => {
        console.log (`Error is : ${error}`)
    })
```

async function **aget_Cards** is defined as per below.
I create a Promise in this function and pass the callbacks *resolve* and *reject* to a lower level function **_aget_Cards**.

```
async function aget_Cards (userCN :string, timeout :number) :Promise<CardDetailsWithCCBal[]|unknown> {
    return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
        _aget_Cards (resolve, reject, userCN, timeout)
    })
}
```

In the lower level function **_aget_Cards**, I use **setTimeout** which invokes the *reject* callback function passed as parameter, and sets a *stop* boolean variable. I had to pass the *reject* callback function as parameter to this function because calling Promise.reject() in the **setTimeout** would not have worked.
Also, I catch any error and *reject* with the error.

```
async function _aget_Cards (resolve :(value :unknown) => void, reject :(reason ?:any) => void, userCN :string, timeout :number)  { 
    
    let start_time = Date.now()
    let stop = false
    
    setTimeout ( () => {
            reject('CONTROLLER_TIMEOUT')
            stop = true
        }
        , timeout
    )

    try {
        if (stop) return
        const cardDetails_lists :CardDetails[][] = await Promise.all ( [
            aget_CardDetails_List (userCN, true),  // Get Primary cards
            aget_CardDetails_List (userCN, false)  // Get Secondary cards
        ])
        console.log(`List of Primary and Secondary Cards obtained in ${(Date.now()-start_time)/1000}s`)
        if (stop) return

        start_time = Date.now()
        const cardDetails_list :CardDetails[] = [...cardDetails_lists[0], ...cardDetails_lists[1]]
        cardDetails_list.sort ( (a, b) => {
            let a_sortVal :string = `${a.cardType}${a.cardNo}`
            let b_sortVal :string = `${b.cardType}${b.cardNo}`
            return (a_sortVal < b_sortVal) ? -1 : (a_sortVal > b_sortVal) ? 1 : 0 
        })
        console.log(`List of Primary and Secondary Cards have been sorted`)
        if (stop) return
        // ...
        console.log(`Fulfilling promise _aget_Cards ...`)
        resolve(cardDetailsWithCCBal_list)
    } catch (error) {
        reject (error)
    }
}
```

I tested the above and it works.

Comment: "*pass the callbacks `resolve` and `reject` to a lower level `async` function `_aget_Cards`.*" - that's still the same antipattern. Also why avoid the use of an abort signal? It's very much appropriate here. Does the code in my answer not work for you?

Comment: As recommended, I use a **single** Promise. The `async function _aget_Cards` returns **void**. It is **async** only because it has await code inside. If an error is raised inside _aget_Cards and I don't `reject` with the error raised, the Promise's catch does not catch that error. That is why I pass `resolve` and `reject` to _aget_Cards, and it works.
Since I did not test abort signal, I cannot be sure if the `throwifAborted` would have been caught by the Promise's catch based on what is explained above. Anyway the implementation I have now works, and I thank you for your recommendations.